# Set Delay on this AJAX Call Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving an error on my AJAX Call, and seems that i need to set delay on everytime i loop on my second ajax call. But i cant make it work.

This is my 1st ajax call, inside this ajax call has a jquery each loop that call the 2nd ajax call. I add setTimeout function but i still got the error message on console "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```
$.ajax({
            url: mysite.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'test_ajax_function',
                'user_input': user_input_last
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $(".container").css("opacity", 1);
                $("#loading-img").css({"display": "none"});

                var array_data = data.split("||");

                var items_count = array_data[0];
                var items = array_data[1];



                jQuery.each(JSON.parse(items), function() {

                setTimeout(function(){    
                getItemDetails(this);
                }, 3000);

                });



            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

This is the 2nd ajax call.

```
function getItemDetails(id) {

    var item_id = id;

        $.ajax({
            url: mysite.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'getItem',
                'id': item_id
            },
            success:function(data) {

            console.log(data);

            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });    

}    


});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first ajax call, don't pass `this` as the parameter for `getItemDetails`, that's what's causing your error.

Aince it seems `getItemDetails` expects the parameter to be an item's ID, just do this:

```
jQuery.each(JSON.parse(items), function(index, item) {
    getItemDetails(item.id);  //<------ I'm assuming 'id' is the name of the property
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for posting answer, the code is actually work, i get some of the details i need from ajax call but to some i got error 508 that some says its because my ajax call is inside a loop. it just happen i need to add delay because of some restriction from hosting. How can i do it, to add delay on every loop.

Comment: Well, your second ajax call is indeed inside a loop, but not an infinite one, which is what [508](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/508) complains about. `jQuery.each(JSON.parse(items))` is not infinite, because there are no infinite items in `items`, are there? If you want you can try delaying the calls using `setTimeout` like you are doing in your code sample. If that doesn't work, I'll need more info to help, like the length of `items` when the error occurs and any other piece of info you might think is important to include in the question